# How an user set his own password while creating account

Tags: users

When a user creates an account he is only asked for a username and email.

I also want him to set his own password when he creates an account. how can i manage that as admin?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this module is for you: [User registration password](https://drupal.org/project/user_registrationpassword)

Answer (score 1):

I like the [logintoboggan](http://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module.  It lets you change a ton of settings for user registration including the one you're looking for and letting users login with their email as well as their usernames.

Comment: thank you very much.. i am really beginner and i will definitly keep this in my mind and will install this one in the later versions..